# location.pathname vs router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am still learning react router v4. and I'd like to know what exactly is the difference between doing this

getting location using

```
const {
      match,
      location,
      layoutBoxed,
      navCollapsed,
      navBehind,
      fixedHeader,
      sidebarWidth,
      theme,
    } = this.props;
```

**Option 1**

```
if(location.pathname === '/500'){
        return <Page500 />
```

and  this
**Option 2**

```
<Route path={'/500'} component={Page500} />
```

As for me, while the first option displays everything properly for me,
the 2nd one i.e. the router one, shows the component in only half the page.
Now, why is that happening?
Option 1 result --> [image]
Option 2 result --> [image]
But the main point--> what is the difference between using location.path name and router

Comment: How are you getting the location prop to the component?

Comment: Can you provide the **Option 2** code?

Comment: okay, you can see option 2 now

Comment: yes thanks. Can you post the code for your first option? I need to see how you are getting the location prop in the component.

Comment: okay, you'll be able see where I am getting the props now

Answer (score 1):

In **Option 2** `<Route path={'/500'} component={Page500} />`
Here you are creating a Route which has a path of /500 and loads a component `Page500`. This means that when the user navigates to the path specified in the Route, React-Router will render the component where the Route was defined.

In **Option 1** ,

```
if(location.pathname === '/500'){
        return <Page500 />
 }
```

the parent component decides when to render the `Page500` component, based on the `location` prop which it receives. This `location` prop would ultimately be coming from a Route or the `withRouter` HOC. This is equivalent to

```
<Route render={(props)=>{
            if(props.location.pathname === '/500'){
                            return <Page500 />;
             }else{
             return null;
             }
          }
        }
   />
```

which can also be written as

`<Route path={'/500'} component={Page500} />`

So to sum it up, you can only do Option 1 if you get the location prop from the parent component, you can define a Route (Option 2) anywhere in the application.

Edit:
If you have all your Routes like

```
return( <div> 
    <Route path={'/500'} component={Page500} />
    <Route path={'/confirm-email'} component={PageConfirmEmail} /> 
    <Route path={'/lock-screen'} component={PageLockScreen} /> 
    <Route path={'/login'} component={PageLogin} /> 
    <Route path={'/sign-up'} component={PageSignUp} />
     <Route path={'/forgot-password'} component={PageForgotPassword} />
    <Route path={'/fullscreen'} component={PageFullscreen} />

</div> );
```

you are running the risk of multiple Routes rendering which might be why you are getting half page render in Option 2. To prevent that from happening and only render the first Route that matches, you should add a `Switch`

```
return( <div> 
   <Switch>
    <Route path={'/500'} component={Page500} />
    <Route path={'/confirm-email'} component={PageConfirmEmail} /> 
    <Route path={'/lock-screen'} component={PageLockScreen} /> 
    <Route path={'/login'} component={PageLogin} /> 
    <Route path={'/sign-up'} component={PageSignUp} />
     <Route path={'/forgot-password'} component={PageForgotPassword} />
    <Route path={'/fullscreen'} component={PageFullscreen} />
   </Switch>
</div> );
```

More on `Switch` can be found at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: is that the reason for the incomplete rendering?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check the link and the example they have given there. Something similar might be going on with your code which is causing multiple routes to get rendered , which in turn makes the first Route render in half the screen.

Comment: well, I added the switch and it didnt make a difference to the rendering issue.

Comment: can you reproduce your issue at codesandbox.io and share it?

Comment: well, this is part of a big project, and I am not sure if I will be able to reproduce the issue at codesandbox. but I will try and share it here. it will be a little later though.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features with react router is that you can do stuff such as:

```
<Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
```

and `id` will be passed into `User` component.

Ex. `/user/bob` and `/user/jill` will both render a `User` component, but in your `componentDidMount` you can now fetch the correct user information from your API.

With `location.pathname` that task becomes more convoluted as @palsrealm mentioned. But first of all, the `location` prop must be available for this method to work.

There are other features that you would be losing out, but that is the main one I can think of so far. You can check out the `Route` api [documentation here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route).

**EDIT:** As for why it is rendering differently, I really can't answer without more context. For example, is the `Route` wrapped in a `Switch` component like so:

```
<Switch>
    // Other routes
    <Route exact path="/500" component={Page500} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I agree that "With location.pathname that task becomes more convoluted". But you would not need to split the path to get the id yourself. You should use the `match` prop; specifically `match.params.id` to get the id if you are doing it yourself.

Comment: no. the routes are inside a div only

 ```return(
      <div>
     
      <Route path={'/500'} component={Page500} />
      <Route path={'/confirm-email'} component={PageConfirmEmail} />
      <Route path={'/lock-screen'} component={PageLockScreen} />
      <Route path={'/login'} component={PageLogin} />
      <Route path={'/sign-up'} component={PageSignUp} />
      <Route path={'/forgot-password'} component={PageForgotPassword} />
      <Route path={'/fullscreen'} component={PageFullscreen} />
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Edited my answer based on @faraz's comments